# Event handling in spreadsheet using spreadjs

Tags: spreadsheet

I  am using spreadjs for manipulting data in the view in which user can change some value,can anyone suggest me that how i  can dynamically get that changed value on the fly for updating in to database?

Answer (score 1):

Bind to the CellChanged event:

```
<div id="ss" style="height:500px;border:solid gray 1px;display:none">

...

var spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");

spread.bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.CellChanged, function (e, args) {
   if (args.propertyName == "value") {
      var updatedValue = sheet.getValue(args.row, args.col);
      // CODE HERE TO SAVE TO SEND TO A SERVICE/WRITE TO DB
   }
});
```

If you want the value as it is being entered, before it is actually committed to the cell, then bind to the EditChange event instead:

```
spread.bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.EditChange,
   function (e, args) {
      var updatedValue = args.editingText;
      // CODE HERE TO SAVE TO SEND TO A SERVICE/WRITE TO DB
});
```